# running F-test with categorical variables

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, jupyter-notebook, statsmodels

```
survey["q3_4"]=survey["q3_4"].astype('category') 
survey["q3_7"]=survey["q3_7"].astype('category')
```

I am running an OLS regression and converted two continuous ordinal variables to catgeorical using the above code. When I run an F-test I cannot figure out how to select `g3_7 (3)` or say `g3_7 (5)`. If I run a regression I see something like `q3_7[T.5.0]` for #5 etc.

Comment: Please provide more context. I guess this is for OLS with the formula interface using statsmodels based on the tags. Which F-test? Do you have an example for the null hypothesis?

Comment: I just want to compare that they are statistically different. I also used results2=smf.ols('q1_7~q3_1+q3_2+q2_13b+q2_13a+C(q3_4)+C(q3_7)', data=survey).fit()

Comment: `results2.f_test('q3_7[T.3.0] = q3_7[T.5.0], q3_7[T.2.0] = q3_7[T.5.0]')` When specifying hypotheses with strings, then the parameter names as specified for example in summary have to be used. Those are the names that patsy created in the formula handling and recognizes for translating test strings into restriction matrices.

Comment: `anova_lm` automatically creates the f tests for the null hypothesis that a categorical explanatory variable has no effect.

Comment: You can edit your question so that it is more self contained and explains the context, which will improve its usefulness for future readers.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!